# Memory map of C program with no global and local variables

Tags: c, memory

I write a basic code as

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  return 0;
}
```

and check its size as

gcc -Wall test1.c

size a.out

```
text    data     bss     dec     hex   filename
 988     260       8    1256     4e8    a.out
```

Just for knowledge i want to know that i do not declare any variable global or local, initialize or uninitialized then why data and bss is shown as 260 and 8 respectively.
Is this for stack pointer and other variables required for code execution ?

Comment: Yes. You are thinking right.

Comment: Ask your friendly, neighbourhood linker to generate a map file.

Comment: Keep in mind that `main` is not the actual entry point to a program. The C runtime library provides the actual entry point (which does a bunch of work, using the stack and global variables) that eventually calls `main`. You can look at your compiled binary with a disassembler to see this.

Comment: Hi Martine James i generate map file using command                  gcc -o test.exe -Wl,-Map,test.map test.c                                        but not finding any usefull info in .map file

Comment: HI Martin James I am unable to understand .map file w.r.t. data and bss segments..